How to remove existing user assigned managed identity from redis cache
 ArmClient ARMClientRM = new ArmClient(IdentityClientCredential, SubscriptionId.ToString())

 ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(SubscriptionId.ToString(), ResourceGroup.Name);

 ResourceGroupResource ResourceGroupResource = ArmClientRM.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);

UserAssignedIdentityData userIdentity = GetUserIdenitity(IdentityName).GetResult();

UserAssignedIdentityResource identityResource = ResourceGroupResource.GetUserAssignedIdentityAsync(IdentityName).GetResult();

ManagedServiceIdentity managedIdentity = 
new ManagedServiceIdentity(ManagedServiceIdentityType.UserAssigned);
 managedIdentity.UserAssignedIdentities.Add(
     userIdentity.Id, null);

RedisPatch patch = new RedisPatch()
{
 RedisConfiguration = new RedisCommonConfiguration()
 {
   PreferredDataPersistenceAuthMethod = "sas",
   AofStorageConnectionString0 = connectionstring1,
   AofStorageConnectionString1 = connectionstring2,
 }
   Identity = managedIdentity
};

RedisCollection redisCollection = ResourceGroupResource.GetAllRedis();

RedisResource resource = redisCollection.GetAsync(clusterName).GetResult();

resource.UpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, patch).GetResult();

I m switching back from managed identity to connection string based authentcation for redis cache. But I couldnt remove the exisiting user assigned managed identity from the cache
Identity = null is not removing the identity linked with redis cluster, I guess it is not considering null value , but I want to remove the usermanagedidentity linked to the cache, Is there any way.
Error

ERROR: Content:
ERROR: {"error":{"code":"FailedIdentityOperation","message":"Identity operation for resource '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Cache/Redis/xxx' failed with error 'Failed to perform resource identity operation. 
Status: 'BadRequest'. 
Response: '{\"error\":{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":
\"Removal of all user-assigned identities assigned to resource '/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/TEstRGSandBox1/providers/Microsoft.Cache/Redis/xxx' 
with type 'UserAssigned' is invalid.\"}}'.'."}}
  



I'm switching back from managed identity to connection string-based authentication for Redis cache. However, I couldn't remove the existing user-assigned managed identity.

You can use the same C# code to authenticate with a connection string for Redis cache.
To remove the existing user-assigned managed identity from Redis cache, you can use the Azure CLI commands below.
Command:
 az redis identity remove --mi-user-assigned "venkatmg" --name "testvenkat" --resource-group "xxxxx"
{
  "principalId": null,
  "tenantId": null,
  "type": "UserAssigned",
  "userAssignedIdentities": {
    "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/vxxxx": {
      "clientId": "9bexxxx87571f85",
      "principalId": "573f9xxxxc1461b"
    }
  }
}



Reference:
az redis identity | Microsoft Learn

ManagedServiceIdentity managedIdentity = new ManagedServiceIdentity(ManagedServiceIdentityType.UserAssigned);
managedIdentity.UserAssignedIdentities.Add(
userIdentity.Id, null);
I tried this but got an error
ERROR: {"error":{"code":"FailedIdentityOperation","message":"Identity operation for resource '/redisclusterxxx' failed with error 'Failed to perform resource identity operation. Status: 'BadRequest'. Response "message":"Removal of all user-assigned identities assigned to resource 'redisclusterxxx' with type 'UserAssigned' is invalid."}}'.'."}}

Edit the question with full code for better understanding.

Please update the code how your code is connected and add full code.

I have updated the code, I use armclient to connect to the cache and managed identity

Any reference link of which code you are trying because this is half of code?

I have added the full code please cehck now

If you need any more details, Please ask

Instead of .net code you can easily remove the managed identity through cli commands for authentication with connection string you can able to use .net code?

Also, you can raise a new question with detailed information in.net(With full code). if you are looking only   in .net so other community people will help you.
